# Share/Sync comments between two Wordpress installs on same database

Tags: wordpress, mobile, synchronization, comments

I purchased a mobile theme for my desktop site but the mobile theme requires it's own Wordpress install. So I've got the desktop site .com and mobile site on a subdomain on the same database, just different Wordpress installs.

I know you can share users and user meta by putting this in the mobile theme's wp-config:

```
define('CUSTOM_USER_TABLE', 'wp_users');
define('CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE', 'wp_usermeta');
```

But is there any way to share **comments** between 2 Wordpress installs on same database? So if user "x" replies on a post on my desktop site, the comment will also show on my mobile site for that same post (and vice versa).

The database entry for desktop Wordpress comments is **wp_commentmeta** and **wp_comments**

For Mobile Wordpress it's **wp_mobilecommentmeta** and **wp_mobilecomments**

Is it possible? I've tried installing Multisite but for some reason it does not install correctly, I get a redirect loop or error establishing database, I think some plugin in my database is causing the problem...so I have to rule out multisite/network as an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that works good enough. On my mobile site (2nd wordpress install) inside the wp-includes folder, I edited the file **wp-db.php** above line 818 (probably can put it anywhere though) and put this code:

```
$tables['comments'] = 'wp_comments';
$tables['commentmeta'] = 'wp_commentmeta';
```

Now when I comment on my desktop site, the comment also shows on mobile site and vice versa. Only problem is if you delete a comment the total comments number will not reflect it. Not a big deal for me.